# Badge not showing on application icon iOS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I sent a push notification with a badge but it does not increase the number on an app icon. I see one thing under phone notification my app does not have an option for a badge. Anybody knows how I can badge option will appear under application setting in the notification window. [image: notification image]

Comment: Please show your payload content. It should contain `badge` value then your app can display that value into app icon

Comment: Thanks, it's my bad I am only passing sound and alert type during authorization call.

Comment: Check the APNS Payload, badge key should be there in order to update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix for this If you won't pass `UNAuthorizationOptionBadge` during `requestAuthorizationWithOptions` in a setting of your application notification does not show badge option and ultimately you will not receive badge notification whether from server-side you're sending a notification with a badge.

```
UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
center.delegate = self;
[center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionAlert + UNAuthorizationOptionSound + UNAuthorizationOptionBadge)
                      completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                        // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
                        [[Appboy sharedInstance] pushAuthorizationFromUserNotificationCenter:granted];
                      }];
```